# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found in pycharm with python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, opencv

I have already installed opencv-python library but when i import it into the the compiler it does not work. I have also tried to install it using pip install opencv-python but it says Requirement already satisfied:. Which means that library is installed but still not works. I am  using pycharm community edition and python 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

try to install this

> pip install opencv-python-headless